# How to Replace Single Quoted String With a Variable with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

I'm trying to replace some text in a file as described in title. What i tried:

```
newdir=/dir/to/my/file
sed -i "s/'MyDir'/${newdir}/g" myconf.conf
```

The command above gives this error:

> unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$newdir` contains `/` characters, so your `sed` command ends up looking like `s/'MyDir'//dir/to/my/file/g`, which won't work -- the first `/` effectively terminates your `sed` expression, and everything else is garbage.

Fortunately, `sed` let's you use *any* character as a delimiter to the `s` command, so you could write instead:

```
sed -i "s|'MyDir'|${newdir}|g" myconf.conf
```

Comment: Though unfortunately, a path can contain any other character that you might use as the delimiter. You always have to be aware of the contents of `newdir`, as you aren't passing a parameter to `sed`: you are building a `sed` script dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around the "does my data contain the delimiter" problem is to use shell variable expansion to escape the delimiter character:

```sh
sed -i "s|'MyDir'|${newdir//|/\\|}|g" myconf.conf
```

Demo:

```sh
$ newdir="/a/dir/with|a/pipe"

$ sed "s|'MyDir'|${newdir}|g" <<< "this is 'MyDir' here"
sed: 1: "s|'MyDir'|/a/dir/with|a ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'a'

$ sed "s|'MyDir'|${newdir//|/\\|}|g" <<< "this is 'MyDir' here"
this is /a/dir/with|a/pipe here
```

You can do this with the default slash delimiter, with more escapes

```sh
sed -i "s/'MyDir'/${newdir//\//\\\/}/g" myconf.conf
```

Comment: Escaping the delimiter is a good start. However, there may be more symbols which need escaping, for example `&` and `\ ` (especially when it is trailing).